# Slow query using "where in" and "order by select count"

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show post from users that specified user is followed and i have two tables at below. but its query is very slow.

table **user**

```
id | username
1  | name1
2  | name2
3  | name3
..
..
```

table **post**

```
id | poster_id | post_content
1  | 2
2  | 3
3  | 10
..
..
```

table **follow**

```
followerid | followtoid
1          | 2
1          | 3
2          | 10
..
..
```

Assume that all tables have more than 1000 rows.

This's **SQL**

```
SELECT * 
FROM post 
WHERE poster_id IN (
    SELECT followtoid 
    WHERE followerid = $_SESSION['userid']
)
```

And this's the second cast is very slow too.
I want to list all member by order from their total posts.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM user 
 ORDER BY (
     SELECT COUNT(id) 
     FROM post 
     WHERE post_id = user.id
) DESC;
```

Comment: The subquery of your first query isn't even valid.

Answer (score 2):

Try indexing `post.userid`, `post.poster_id`, `followtoid.followerid` and `user.user_id`, using [`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html), and use `LEFT JOIN` clause on your queries instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN SELECT poster_id, COUNT(*) as count FROM post p GROUP BY poster_id  
ON (u.user_id = p.poster_id)
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

and:

```
SELECT * FROM post AS p 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT followerid FROM followtoid) AS f
ON (p.userid=f.followerid)
WHERE p.userid = {$_SESSION['userid']}
```

Comment: I don't think your top query is valid ANSI SQL, as it selects non-aggregate values that are not part of the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Yep. I'm a little rusty on my SQL, I usually have to try once or twice before I got it right (I've made an update, maybe it's right this time :-)) Anyway it's about using LEFT JOIN, properly :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JOIN` for the first query

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM post p
    JOIN follow f ON p.post_id = f.followtoid
WHERE f.followerid = $_SESSION['userid']
```

and a `JOIN` plus a `GROUP BY` for the second

```
SELECT u.*, tbl.postCount
FROM user u
    JOIN (
        SELECT poster_id, COUNT(*) AS postCount
        FROM post p
        GROUP BY posterID
    ) tbl ON tbl.poster_id = u.id
ORDER BY postCount DESC
```

Comment: thanks @Patrick Q it worked, can you give an invert of first query for me. select post from all users not followed.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a "write this code for me" site. Make an attempt to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the second query without a subquery:

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(p.poster_id) as postCount
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN post p
    ON (u.user_id = p.poster_id)
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY postCount DESC;
```

Comment: Except that that is not valid/compliant ANSI SQL.